# Getting [error] Element css=input.logon_button.logon_button_hover not found in Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.0 firefox addon
Trying automate the URL testing
But I get the following error when I try to automate the login,

`[error] Element css=input.logon_button.logon_button_hover not found`

Comment: You need to adjust your css/xpath selector. It's not finding the element on the page. It's that simple. This could be because you're copying the css from when you're hovered on it. Take off the last part and try and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it's a variable element. The hover part may only show while you are hovering over the link, which you won't be when selenium is running. Rather that right clicking and using the command, or selecting from selenium, view the html for your page and find the element in the code while you aren't hovering over it, to ensure it isn't different.